# console.log & debugger statements in React.Components - unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, console.log, javascript-debugger, es6-class

What is the proper way to add `console.log` and `debugger` statements to my React.Components?

Just dropping them in produces `Unexpected token` errors:

```js
export class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {
  debugger;
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
```

A little more helpful but still produces `Unexpected 'debugger' statement`:

```js
export class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    debugger;
```

Or even browsers' `console` errors out `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`:

```js
class Woot {
    debugger;
}
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error in your second example:
http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/JEPPxR

Comment: The `class` body can only contain method declarations. You cannot put arbitrary statements inside the body. Putting the `debugger` statement in the constructor should work. If you get *"Unexpected 'debugger' statement"*, then that might be a linter warning, and of course can be ignored when you are actually debugging. Are you using a linter?

Comment: Confirmed, setting `debugger` in the constructor works, when testing in the browser's console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your debugger statement inside the constructor or a function and it'll work fine.